# How to retrieve data from database in (Async fastapi) sqlalchemy as a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, database, asynchronous, sqlalchemy

I am trying to retrieve data from my sql database (in async fastapi) as a pandas dataframe

```
database = databases.Database(DATABASE_URL)
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL, future=True, echo=False)
async_session = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)
Base = declarative_base()
```

Above is how I am establishing connection to the database.

```
async def get_all_exercises(session):
    found_exercise = pd.read_sql(select(models.Exercises), session.bind)
    print(type(found_exercise))
    return found_exercise

    
async with async_session() as session:
    async with session.begin():
        print(get_all_exercises(session))
```

But while running this I am getting an error that, `AttributeError: 'AsyncEngine' object has no attribute 'cursor'`

Comment: If you could add the full traceback that would help us as we'd know where exactly to look